# How to post and request data to a controller method in Laravel using JQuery and bootstrap multi step forms?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I want to send multi step form data to a controller method when i click the save button and later request that data in the controller method using Jquery. I have tried some steps but even the button doesn't seem to do anything.

I have this route to store treatment data.

```
Route::post('/patients/{patient}/medications','PatientMedicationsController@store')->name('saveTreatment')->middleware('auth');
```

These are some of the ids of my fields whose data i want to save.

```
heartRate, bloodPressure, otherFindings, duration
```

And id of the submit button is `save`.
i have this Jquery code in my blade view.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#save').click( function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:("route('saveTreatment')"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit': true},
        success: function () {
            alert('Treatment has been saved');
           }
         });
       });
   });
</script>
```

The controller method to store is `store`.

I want the multi step form data to be received by the controller method and then saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the route in blade syntax within your ajax call:

```
{{ route('saveTreatment', $patient->id) }}
```

So the entire ajax call would look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#save').click( function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:("{{ route('saveTreatment', $patient->id) }}"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit': true},
        success: function () {
            alert('Treatment has been saved');
           }
         });
    });
});
```

If your ajax call is in a separate file then you could add a data attribute to the form such as data-ajax-url="{{ route('saveTreatment', $patient->id) }}".

Your ajax call would then look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#save').click( function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:($('.form-class').attr('data-ajax-url')),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit': true},
        success: function () {
            alert('Treatment has been saved');
           }
         });
    });
});
```

You could also simply write the url as:

```
url:("/patients/" + {{ $patient->id }} + "/medications"),
```

You also need to make sure that any return value from the controller is wrapped in a json_encode();

Comment: My ajax call is within my blade file where the form resides but i now get this problem    `Missing required parameters for [Route: saveTreatment] [URI: patients/{patient}/medications]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\KVS\resources\views\patients\show.blade.php)`   After the changing to this.    `$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#save').click( function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:($('.form-class').attr('data-ajax-url')),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit': true},
        success: function () {
            alert('Treatment  saved');
           }
         });
    });
});`

Comment: Apologies, the route method needs a second parameter which would be the patient id, so the data attribute on the form should be data-ajax-url="{{ route('saveTreatment', $patient->id) }}"